# What is the domain of $f(z) = \mathop{Arg} \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What is the domain of:

$$
f(z) = \mathop{Arg} \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)
$$

I would have guessed simply $z \neq 0$.

My textbook gives the answer $\mathop{Re} z \neq 0$

Why would $\pm i$ be outside of the domain of this function? It would seem that $f(i) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f(-i) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and that $\pm i$ are in the domain of the function.

Comment: Well you need to do a branch cut in order to have a single valued function. Since clearly $0$ is not in the domain, removing any line that passes trough the origin will give you a well defined function. However, usually the books reserve $Arg$ (with capital "A") for a specific branch of the argument function. So, in this case the line that you want to remove is the one that yields your pre-established branch for $Arg$.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Could you perhaps provide more context on how your textbook defines $\mathrm{Arg}()$? My usual interpretation would lead me also to conclude that the domain is $z \neq 0$.